# android: How to manage memory between application starts (application failure on second run)?

Tags: android, memory-management

Noob question!

My whiteboard/drawing app runs fine, using a combination of simple image views and bitmaps with me rendering a path to a bitmap and copying over as needed. I have it multitasking on my ICS Transformer without problems. However, if I exit the app with the Back button and then run it again, it fails; I get a memory error on the second run when I try to draw something.

```
Out of memory on a 4096016-byte allocation
```

Although sometimes I don't get that and it runs a second consecutive time. When I run it a third time, it works, and the fourth, again it Out-of-memory's.

What manual cleanup do I have to do when an Android app exits? Should I remove all created objects and bitmaps and paths and listeners and stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a memory leak. Make sure you follow recommendations provided [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). Often [Memory Analyzer Tool](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.eclipse.org/mat/&ei=nNWST7eABKeF4gTis8jQDw&usg=AFQjCNHJQkRWSlJy95ScA7QeIngK8cejpQ&sig2=qDHI676umCnv6zVsws8Tqw) is very useful in such cases. Here is [a video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html) how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. That's something I have to sit down and work through. Memory management is new to me!

Comment: The first link is broken!